# My Tumblr blog disappeared

Tags: blog, tumblr

Did something like that ever happen to anyone ?

My Tumblr blog disappeared ([http://blog.gitwatcher.com](http://blog.gitwatcher.com/)).

I've already emailed the support, but no response at all.

(last) UPDATE 
... in responce @Ciaran (see his answer)

I read [Tumblr's Content Policy](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/content) twice and in my understanding, there wasn't any violation. Moreover I didn't received any email from Tumblr to the address I signed up with.

(previous) UPDATE
… more infos

First of all, the worst thing is that if I try to login, I get a “[suspended page](https://www.tumblr.com/suspended)”: “the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete” error page.

That said, if you try to click http://blog.gitwatcher.com you get a “Not found - We couldn't find the page you were looking for.” ( 404 http error ). If you try to click http://gitwatcher.tumblr.com the same, you'll get a “Not found - We couldn't find the page you were looking for.” ( 404 http error ).

If you run `nslookup` on both the domains you’ll get the following:

```
Name:    blog.gitwatcher.com
Address:  72.32.231.8

Name:    gitwatcher.tumblr.com
Address:  50.22.53.157
```

where the last IP is:

```
Name:    50.22.53.157-static.reverse.softlayer.com
Address:  50.22.53.157
```

Moreover, I can reach the server responsable to redirect any second level Tumblr blog domain request to a custom domain name, so that server for some reason and without any warning doesn't do the job anymore:

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ ping 72.32.231.8
PING 72.32.231.8 (72.32.231.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 72.32.231.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=147 ms
64 bytes from 72.32.231.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=149 ms
64 bytes from 72.32.231.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=50 time=339 ms
^C
--- 72.32.231.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 147.527/212.135/339.744/90.236 ms
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$
```

Why?

Comment: More details needed. What do you mean by disappeared? I had an issue previously where Tumblr forgot my custom domain settings and reverted to exampleblog.tumblr.com. But the blog was still available via the Tumblr dashboard.

Comment: see the UPDATE ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, 
after sending many "asking for question" around the Internet, "tweets", "e-mailing to support",

but most important, after **24 hours of downtime**, I get a response from Tumblr support:

```
Your request (Ticket 606267) has been updated.

You can respond by replying to this email.


[anonymizer], Jan-09 11:43 (EST):

Hello Luca

There was a glitch on our end. My apologies. 
You may need to delete your cookies and cache 
but you should be able to access your blog now.

– to delete your web browser cache -

http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache


– To deleting your web browser's cookies for Tumblr.com -

http://www.aboutcookies.org/Default.aspx?page=2

thanks
[anonymizer]
```

All's Well That Ends Well ... and 
I'll give them a second chance but ...

UPDATE :
I may have spoken too early, the blog is up but we can't access administrative dashboard. Even after cleaning up browser cache and cookies I cannot login, getting a [suspended page](https://www.tumblr.com/suspended) ... still waiting for an answer ...

UPDATE : 
another ~40 hours 
and also administrative issue with dashboard login is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your blog has been suspended. Check to see if you are in violation of [Tumblr's Content Policy](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/content).

> If you are found to be in violation of any of the below policies, you
>   will receive a notice via email. Unless you explain or correct your
>   behavior within 72 hours, your account will be suspended. We will do
>   our best to work with you and ensure a fair outcome in all cases. We
>   reserve the right to immediately suspend, without notice, any content,
>   account, or IP address which we determine to be systematically
>   generated, spam, or potentially damaging to our service or
>   infrastructure.
>
> When your account is suspended, public access to your content is
>   blocked, and your Tumblr URL (and custom domain if applicable) is
>   redirected to the Tumblr home page. Access to your Tumblr Dashboard
>   and the ability to add/edit posts is also disabled.

Additionally, check to see if you received an email from Tumblr to the address you signed up with.

Comment: I didn't receive any notice at all ...

Comment: ... and even worse, I cannot reach any Tumblr domain too, so I cannot read Tumblr's Content Policy anymore ...

Comment: @LucaG.Soave but can you access it/them from another IP?

Comment: https://184.173.74.9/policy/en/conten is locked uot too

Comment: Ok I get it by trashing out all cookies coming from Tumblr ... WTF!

Comment: I read Tumblr's Content Policy twice and in my understanding, there wasn't any violation. See UPDATE

Comment: Send an email to Tumblr support asking them specifically about the suspension. Nothing more that we can do for you here. Good luck.