# Tumblr blog not loading

Tags: tumblr

My tumblr blog ([blog.tonyhue.com](http://blog.tonyhue.com)) often doesn't load. Instead, I get that blasted

> "This webpage is not available"

message on Chrome, etc. Repeatedly hitting refresh sometimes seems to cure. 
Any clues?

Comment: Not just in chrome I tried to find the problem but even in Safari, IE the rendering of the page is not proper. I guess the developer has messed up attaching the external css

Comment: ya its not loading in firefox too!!

Comment: Please supply info about what support has told you (or not), assuming you _did_ try to contact them.

Comment: Are you still facing those problems? Were any of the answers given, helpful?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that another user recently had the [same issue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22586/my-tumblr-blog-disappeared). In brief, the problem was server side and could only be fixed by support. The user was also required to clear his cookies.

This is most likely not an error with your template. 'Not Found' almost always means a 404 error (source could not be found).

Even though there is not a human readable error code on that 'Not Found' page, I checked the source and found the following in the body:

var status_code = '404'

Yup, it's a 404 error! This probably doesn't have anything to do with your template or your blog personalizations. If your browser were loading the content partially or receiving the content but unable to render it, you would be receiving an error code in the 200s. Instead, it's unable to find the directory of your content.

Support will have to fix this for you, probably by repairing an error with their DNS.

Another possibility: you somehow violated Tumblr's user policy. If that is the case, they will notify you within 72 hours.

I hope this helped!

Comment: +1 for the "same issue" link. That answer has a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must be having some issues with the theme that you may be using. Try changing the theme or css to be exact.
If this doesn't solve your problem try contacting Tumblr Support. They will definitely help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom domain's A-record is pointing at the most up-to-date IP address at http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains. Currently, that's `66.6.44.4`.

I saw this exact same problem on three different old Tumblr blogs with custom domains pointing at an A-record target from an older version of their documentation. This fixed the problem for all three.